# Orchard CMS and handling of Organisations with Users...?

Tags: orchardcms

I know that you have users, roles and permission in Orchard. However is it possible to have organisations above users?

Many thanks,

Ed

Comment: Anything is possible, if you write a module for it. Not out of the box however.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, could you provide as an answer then I will mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is possible, if you write a module for it. Not out of the box however.